# Elastic search API Vs Spring data Vs logstash

Tags: spring, postgresql, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am planing to use elastic search for our dashboard using spring boot based rest services. After research i see top 3 options

**Option A:**

1. Use [Elastic Search Java API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs.html) ( from comment looks like going to go away)
2. Use Elastic [Search Java Rest Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/index.html)
3. Use [spring-data-elasticsearch](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-elasticsearch) ( planing to use es 5.6 but challenging for latest es 6 as I don't see it's supports right now)

**Option B:**

Or shall I use logstash approach to
 Sync data between postgressql and elastic search using [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin) ?

Which one among them will be long term approach to get near real time data from ES in high load scenario  ??

Usecase: I need to save some data from postgresql table to elastic search for my dashboard (near real time )

Update is frequent for both tables and  es 
to maintain current state

Load is going to increase in couple of week

Comment: This is a bit strange list of options. The 3 and 4 are higher level libraries/frameworks which use either 1 or 2. So, it's really a question of what is more convenient for you and what kind of configuration they expose and if you can bend it to your requirements. One thing to note is that Java API client [is doomed, and the plan is that everyone will use REST client going forward](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html)

Comment: Sorry updated question.. I am planning to use spring-data-elastic but wanted to make sure if it is a right choice as every time I need to make sure to save to es or shall I use logstash to sync data ?

Answer (score 1):

The options you listed, in essence, are: should you go with a ready to use solution (logstash) or should you implement your own.

Try logstash first to see if it works for you - it'll take less time than implementing your own solution, and you can get working solution in minutes (if it's not hundreds of tables)

If you want near-real time, then you need to figure out if it allows you to:

- handle incremental updates, i.e. if its 'tracking_column' configuration will work for your data structure and it will only load updated records in each run, not the whole table.
- run it at the desired frequency
- and in general, satisfies your latency requirements

If you decide to go with your own solution, keep in mind that spring-data-elasticsearch is a higher level wrapper for underlying elasticsearch client. If there are latency goals, then working on the lower level (elasticsearch clients) may give you better control and more options to tune the pipeline.

Otherwise, the client choice will not matter that much as data feed features (volume/update frequency) and db/es cluster configuration.